# Testing the variance of betadisper() output

Tags: r, vegan

I have some population genomics data where I have allele frequencies of SNPs with respect to the ancestral genome for each treatment.

I wanted to look whether beta diversity was different between treatments so used the `vegan` package and `betadisper()` on euclidean distances.

After extracting all the information from the model and putting it into dataframes so that ggplot2 likes it I can get this plot.

[image]

Although to my eye this shows higher beta diversity in mixed (circle) than static (triangle) treatments, the `anova()`, `permutest()` and `TukeyHSD()` methods give results where we do not reject the null hypothesis of homogeneity of variances. In addition, the p values for most of these tests are p > 0.8.

From what I can work out, these tests on a `betadisper()` model object look at differences in the mean distance to the centroid, which is not different across treatments.

[image]

However the spread of distance to centroid does seem to be different between the treatments.

I was just wondering if I am ok doing something like a Bartlett test or levene test (in the `car` package) to look at differences in the variance of the distances from the centroid for each group as another metric of "beta diversity" (variance across groups). Or if there are methods within vegan that anyone knows to look at the variance of distance to centroid as well as the changes in the mean distance to centroid.

Answer (score 3):

Your graphics are misleading: You should use equal aspect ratio (isometric scaling) in PCoA, but the horizontal axis is stretched and vertical axis compressed in your plot. Moreover, the convex hull can be misleading as it focuses on extreme observations, but the test focuses on "typical" distances from the centroid. So your "eye" was wrong and misled by graphics. We do provide correct graphics as methods for `betadisper` and using these instead of self-concocted **ggplot2** graphics would have saved you from this problem, or at least you could use these graphics to cross-check your own versions.

Please note that `betadisper` already works with "homogeneity" of variances, and having a variance of variances (= variance of distances from centroids) may not be a useful or easily interpreted. The pairs of functions we have are `adonis2` for differences of centroids and and `betadisper` for sizes of dispersion w.r.t. to centroids.

Comment: Thanks. After posting this question I had similar thoughts. Could you point me in the direction of information on maintaining an equal aspect ratio for PCoA or PCA plots. I have come from doing ordinations in phyloseq where they advocate changing the axes to demonstrate the variation that each axis explains (Figure 10 [here](https://f1000research.com/articles/5-1492/v1) for example)...

Comment: PCoA axes are standardly scaled by their associated eigenvalue (sometimes expressed as "variation that each axis explains"), but then you must plot the graphics with that scaling, that is, with equal aspect ratio. I don't use **ggplot2** myself: you must dig up that information from their documentation. In standard **R** graphics we just use `asp = 1` argument.

Comment: just add `+ coord_fixed()` or `+ coord_equal()` to your ggplot to get equal axis scaling, which is what Jari mentions. You need to preserve the equal scaling so that Euclidean distances on the plot retain their meaning in PCoA as a 2-d (in this case) approximation to the original distances between samples.